# How to block browser on Android?

Tags: android

I want to implement application that denied access to the browser when user drive a car. I find that I can monitor processes and kill browser but Is it only one way how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no official way that your application can interfere the normal workflow of process to be activated on Android system.
This is due to the fact that each application run on it own Linux process (like a sandbox) to protect it from others application.

That was what learn from my very first day working with Android, don't know if it still right now :-)

More on this can be found here [IBM Article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-androidsecurity/index.html)

Comment: Yes, I know about that, but [this](http://www.10n2tek.com/index.html) company tells that they ahve developed app that blocked surfing and mailing